# PHPMailer wont send mails

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have this PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/

my code is this:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'kms-play.it';  // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'noreply@kms-play.it';                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

    $mail->From = 'noreply@kms-play.it';
    $mail->FromName = 'KMS-Play';
    $mail->addAddress('evolutio@kms-play.it', 'Lars Mehrhoff');  // Add a recipient

    #$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
    #$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    #$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
    #$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
       echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }
    echo 'Message has been sent';
```

and the error is:

> 2013-12-15 15:02:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO local.kms-play.it 2013-12-15 15:02:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2013-12-15 15:02:23 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 502 5.5.1 Error: command not implemented 2013-12-15 15:02:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: You're sure that `kms-play.it` supports a TLS connection?

Comment: By the question title, I though PHPMailer announced a service shut down.

Comment: Without TLS it says: `2013-12-15 15:10:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO local.kms-play.it 2013-12-15 15:10:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2013-12-15 15:10:33 SMTP ERROR: AUTH command failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism 2013-12-15 15:10:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`

Comment: you should specify the ports !! i cant see that you assign a value to the port

Comment: test your smtp server using http://www.test-smtp.com/.

Comment: I would also give http://swiftmailer.org/ a try, you may fare better with it. PHPMailer says it supports "SMTP authentication with LOGIN, PLAIN, NTLM and CRAM-MD5 mechanisms", however in this case it doesn't seem to be able to agree with the server on an AUTH mechanism. I would expect it to try a few more times with different methods, but it is failing after one try. I also can't find any way to specify which AUTH method to use - so you could try them each until one worked.

Comment: @TasosBitsios Swiftmailer works. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1 - As `TLS` is not active comment this line:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

It will work but is not good to send mails without sign them.

2 - Make sure to activate `TLS` and the `EHLO` command should return:

```
EHLO myfriend
2016-10-27 01:15:07 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.urutecno.net 
Hello mail.myfriemd.com [216.111.111.111]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
```

Answer (score 0):

Just config issue.

> update< human -> goto web ::https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases
>   get --> PHPMailer-5.2-stable and browse to examples\mailing_list.phps

add the followin config files to the file and it will work out of the box.

```
     $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

for sure it will work

Comment: This configuration is turning off all validation of the TLS certificate that is being presented to your PHP application. If someone tries to man-in-the-middle your SMTP connection, you'll never know about it.

Answer (score -3):

I guess this might be wrong:

```
$mail->Host = 'kms-play.it';
```

Is that really your SMTP host? Usually it's something like smtp.kms-play.it. Best check with your hosting provider.

Comment: Yes, thunderbirdsettings are the same as in the script. 
I don't find any error in the mail.err/.info or mail.log on the Server

Comment: The connection is being established and the server even responds:
    "502 5.5.1 Error: command not implemented" (edit: premature submission)